# Python Pupil detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect pupils in a image. I used haarcascade classifiers i detected faces and eyes and in those eyes i am using Hough Transform to detect circles(pupils).The following is my code

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
import os

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eyeCascade= cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

img = cv2.imread('me.jpg',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(img)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), 255, 2)
    roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    eyes = eyeCascade.detectMultiScale(roi)
    for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh), 255, 2)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(eyes,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

when i run this code i am getting an error of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Acads\7.1 Sem\BTP\FaceDetect-master\hough transform.py", line 25, in <module>
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(eyes,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
error: ..\..\..\opencv-3.1.0\modules\core\src\array.cpp:2494: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
```

please help me thank you

Comment: You're passing to Hough the result of the detection `eyes`, but you should pass instead the roi of the `img` according to the detection

Comment: yeah but i want to detect pupil present in eyes when i roi getting circles in background. how can i detect pupils in  eyes

Comment: remove the default parameters from this line: circles = cv2.HoughCircles(eyes,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0) ....that is replace it with circles = cv2.HoughCircles(eyes,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20)

Comment: yup done that giving me a whole lot of other errors